# How can I read a png image using libpng?

Tags: visual-c++, boost, libpng, boost-gil

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/png_io.hpp> 
namespace gil = boost::gil;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

     gil::gray8_image_t input;
     gil::png_read_image("..\\resources\\frame10.png",input);

     return 0;

}
```

In the main program I want to read a png image. Debug has no problem. But when I run
the executable file, it crashed. What's the reason? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to your relative path. As far as I remember, Visual starts the debugging session in $PROJECT_DIR. If you launch manually the exe (from $PROJECT_DIR/Debug (or Release)), it might not find your resources.